# Using Blazor wasm I can't access content-disposition response header

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Using Blazor I am making an API call which returns an Excel file, I am trying to access the content-disposition response header which I can see is present using Chrome dev tools :

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=report-285-20200603183055.xlsx; filename*=UTF-8''report-285-20200603183055.xlsx
```

I am using this code but it returns false :

```
if (httpResponseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("content-disposition", out IEnumerable<string> extractedHeaders))
```

How can I access the content-disposition value, I want to extract the filename out?
Just to add, I am exposing the header in Startup.cs ConfigureServices() in the API project :

```
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
            builder
            ...
            .WithExposedHeaders(new string[] { "Location", "location", "Content-disposition","content-disposition" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
Response.Content.Headers
```

To get that header, Response.Headers  does not contain it

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your API CORS policy exposes the header. See this question: [Blazor WASM C# .NET 6 Content-Disposition is not Accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348516/blazor-wasm-c-sharp-net-6-content-disposition-is-not-accessible)