# Blazor WASM C# .NET 6 Content-Disposition is not Accessible

Tags: html, blazor-webassembly

I'm extremely confused as I've been doing web development for many years now. Granted, this is my first time using Bazor and .NET 6.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why I can't get the content-disposition at all?
This should be trivial, but I tried logging all of the headers on the response and I just don't see anything.

My API is returning a file using `File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string? fileDownloadName)` and you can see the `filename` in the response header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I wasn't able to get ANY header value until I updated my API CORS Policy as follows:

[image]

You must expose the headers. I'm not sure why you can see the headers in the response, but Blazor can't, but that's what you have to do.

Comment: Maybe Blazor is stricter, also further reading on the above helped me understand the why, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107459/in-the-http-cors-spec-whats-the-difference-between-allow-headers-and-expose-he